# Jest secure cookies?

Tags: javascript, testing, cookies, jestjs, jsdom

My [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) tests are setup to mock my backend response when run on CI, but an environment variable allows them to run against the real backend locally.

The problem is that we've now switched auth to use secure, http-only cookies. Is it possible to cause Jest to configure jsdom to respect cookies?

I *think* jsdom's `cookieJar` [config](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#how-it-works) might do the trick, but can't figure out how to configure that via jest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's still no implementation for configuring jsdom for Jest

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2460